# How to exclude drf router path from drf_spectacular SERVERS setting

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-spectacular

I would like to verify some best practices when using drf_spectacular with a django project.

I have an API in a django project where all the endpoints use the api/ prefix, i.e. in urls.py, I'm using.

```
path('api/', include('myapp_api.urls')),
```

The myapp_api project'ss urls.py uses the default router, so something like

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'assets', views.AssetsViewSet)
```

By default, this means that the swagger docs will present all the endpoints as something like...

```
/api/assets/{}/
```

instead of

```
/assets{}/
```

At this point, the swagger UI's test calls will work just fine because it will correctly call `https://example.com/api/assets{}/`. It just looks a bit messy in SwaggerUI so it's not ideal. I'm getting the impression that the `/api` is superfluous and should be essentially "handled" by the "servers" value.

A problem arises when I set the OpenAPI server object, which for drf_spectacular is the `SERVERS` setting, e.g.

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SERVERS': [{'url': 'https://example.com/api'}],
}
```

This will result in failures with SwaggerUI test calls because they try to sent requests to the following (not the `/api/api`)

```
https://example.com/api/api/assets/{}/
```

A secondary problem is that the `/api/` prefix will *still* appear on all the SwaggerUI listed endpoints.

I seem to have two options:

1. I could go to my urls.py and use `path('', include('myapp_api.urls'))` instead of `path('api/', include('myapp_api.urls'))` but that's not desirable because the prefixing seems to make sense in this context.
2. I could use a drf_spectacular preprocessing hook and tweak all the endpoints it's generating.

e.g.

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SERVERS': [{'url': 'https://example.com/api'}],
    'PREPROCESSING_HOOKS': ['my_preprocessing_hooks.strip_the_api_prefix']
}


def strip_the_api_prefix(endpoints, **kwargs):
    for i in range(0, len(endpoints)):
        temp = list(endpoints[i])
        if temp[0].startswith('/api'):
            temp[0] = temp[0][4:]
        endpoints[i] = tuple(temp)
    return endpoints
```

My question is, this all seems like a brittle hack and I'm wondering if I'm missing something. I would like to know if I'm following best practices etc.

I'm pretty sure I need to be setting at least one [OpenAPI server](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/) value, so today it's `https://example.com/api` which could always be the 'bleeding edge', but later there could be a `https://api.example.com/v1` if there's multiple major versions in the future that I want to maintain. My understanding is that the OpenAPI `server` value is important for client applications so that there's less need to guess the non-path part of the URL when interacting with an API.

I'm presuming that it's best practices to *not* have prefixes for all the endpoints that are documented in the SwaggerUI, but it seems that drf_spectacular is pulling them automatically from the urls.py files, which is why the `/api` keeps getting added.

So in short, is there a better way to handle this situation that using a preprocessing hook?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used [drf-spectacular](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) before but I had a quick look at the docs and may be able to give you some ideas.

For your DRF urls - `path('api/', include('myapp_api.urls')),`. For different API version you would have different url files, even different views files. For example, non versioned files being your latest "bleeding edge":

```
myapp_api/urls/urls.py  # latest and greatest
myapp_api/urls/v1_urls.py  # older supported urls
```

```
myapp_api/views/views.py  # latest and greatest
myapp_api/urls/v1_views.py  # older supported urls
```

Then you would import the different versions in your main url file:

```
path('api/', include('myapp_api.urls.urls')),
path('api/v1/', include('myapp_api.urls.v1_urls')),
```

For your drf-spectacular, You may not need to implement `SERVERS` but if you do, it may be possible to do the below. I haven't used this package before though. [Here's the documentation](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=server) I've looked at for this settings.

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SERVERS': [
        {'url': 'https://example.com/api'},
        {'url': 'https://example.com/api/v1'},
    ],
}
```

Having the URLs and views setup with versioning forces versioning as the default. Although when you create a new "bleeding edge" API, it will involve renaming files and imports. **If you don't want this**, an alternative setup could be:

You keep track of the API by versioning them in the file names, where v1 is the oldest, and you increment for each iteration. So if you had v1, v2 and v3, v3 would be the latest. This would be `urls/v1_urls.py`, `urls/v2_urls.py` and so on. You would then only update the main urls file to point to the latest version. For example:

```
# Older supported APIs
path('api/v1/', include('myapp_api.urls.v1_urls')),
path('api/v2/', include('myapp_api.urls.v2_urls')),

# Latest API
path('api/', include('myapp_api.urls.v3_urls')),
```

If v4 became the latest, you would move v4 into the latest and move v3 into the oldest and change the URL to be `api/v3/`.

This combined with versioned named files would make it easier to delete retired versions and also add new version without having to rename imports etc.

Comment: Yes, I think the different urls.py file is good for different API versions, but my problem is with how the SwaggerUI is built via drf_spectacular which parses the urls.py files. The best practices for Django, seem at odds with best practices with defining an OpenAPI  server object(s) (which are useful for client apps). The result is a broken SwaggerUI with either incorrect paths when using end point tests, and messy published end points presented with the prfixes e.g. if versioned with api/v1/, there would always be a /api/v1/assets/{}/ listed rather than just /assets/{}.

Comment: In your example in with api/v1/, the problem is the SwaggerUI generated by drf_spectacular is going to document an endpoint like /api/v1/assets{}/, when, what I expect should happens is that there's really a servers value of https://example.com/api/v1 and then a documented endpoint of /assets/{}/. I can only seem to solve this with a prepocessing hook (NB: I edited the original question for clarity).

Answer (score 0):

For replacement ***strip_the_api_prefix*** preprocessing hook you can set **SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX_TRIM** to True in **SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS**.

so it will be

```
/url_path/
```

instead of

```
/api/v1/url_path/
```

in swagger ui